# AZURE Authentication error using REST API in Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, delphi-xe3

I am trying to use the Microsoft AZURE storage service to store files directly from an application, however, as much as I read the authentication documentation [MS Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx) I keep getting authentication errors and can not get past it.
Before anyone askes I can not use the included version on the AssureConnection component as this was compiled with a different version of INDY.  I am using the latest version and its not compatible.  IPPeerClient does not compile.  Howwver, if someone has a version that does compile with the latest INDY version I will be most grateful.

Here is my code for getting a list of blobs in a container, but as mentioned I always get an authentication error. I dont seem to get past authentication to get a result and a list of blobs in the container.

What an I doing wrong?

Please replace yourAccount, yourContainer and yourKey with those provided by the AZURE platform.

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  resultHTTP: string;
  MyHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  AccessKey: string;

  TheDate: string;
  AuthHeader: string;

  RequestMethod: string;
  URLPath: string;
  dateInRfc1123Format: TDateTime;

  canonicalizedHeaders: string;
  canonicalizedResource : string;

  stringToSign: string;
  authorizationHeader: string;

function GetBase64_HMAC_SHA256(const AKey, AStr: string): String;
var
  sha: TIdHMACSHA256;
  KeyBytes: TIdBytes;
  DataBytes: TIdBytes;
  ResBytes: TIdBytes;
begin
  IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary;
  if IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Load() then
  begin
    if TIdHashSHA256.IsAvailable then
    begin
      sha := TIdHMACSHA256.Create;
      sha.Key := BytesOf(UTF8Encode(AKey));
      DataBytes:= BytesOf(UTF8Encode(AStr));
      ResBytes:= sha.HashValue(DataBytes);
    end
    else
      showmessage('Unable to encode');
  end;
  result:= EncodeBase64(ResBytes, Length(ResBytes));
end;

begin

  // Used for streaming the blob later.  Not in use now.
  //aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  //aStream.LoadFromFile('MQ21.JPG');

  RequestMethod:= 'GET';

  dateInRfc1123Format:= TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now);
  TheDate:= formatdatetime('ddd, dd mmm yyyy hh:nn:ss "GMT"',dateInRfc1123Format);
  canonicalizedHeaders:= format('%s\n%s',['x-ms-date:' + TheDate, 'x-ms-version:2014-02-14']);

  URLPath:= format('%s',['comp:list\ninclude:metadata,snapshots,uncommittedblobs\nrestype:container']);
  canonicalizedResource:= format('/%s/%s\n%s',['yourAccount','yourContainer', URLPath]);

  stringToSign:= format('%s\n'+ // request method
                        '\n' + // content encoding
                        '\n' + // content language
                        '\n' + // content length
                        '\n' + // content md5
                        '\n' + // content type
                        '\n' + // date
                        '\n' + // if modified since
                        '\n' + // if match
                        '\n' + // if none match
                        '\n' + // if unmodified since
                        '\n' + // range
                        '%s\n' + // headers
                        '%s', // URL,
                        [RequestMethod,
                        canonicalizedHeaders,
                        canonicalizedResource]);

  authorizationHeader:= GetBase64_HMAC_SHA256('yourKey',stringToSign);
  memo1.Lines.Add('LOG: ' + stringToSign);
  memo1.Lines.Add('LOG: ' + authorizationHeader);

  LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  MyHTTP:= TidHTTP.Create(self);
  MyHTTP.IOHandler:= LHandler;
  MyHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization',format('SharedKey yourAccount:%s',[authorizationHeader]));
  MyHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('x-ms-date',TheDate);
  MyHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('x-ms-version','2014-02-14');

  try
    with MyHTTP do
    begin
      try
        resultHTTP:= MyHTTP.Get('https://yourAccount.blob.core.windows.net/yourContainer?restype=container&comp=list&include=snapshots&include=metadata&include=uncommittedblobs');
      except
        on E: Exception do
          showmessage('Error encountered during HTTP: ' + E.Message);
      end;
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(format('Result: [%s]',[resultHTTP]));
    FreeAndNil(MyHTTP);
    //FreeAndNil(aStream);
  finally

  end;

end;
```

I just don't understand where the authentication is going wrong.  If you have a REST API example yourself, please feel free to share.

Comment: When authentication fails, the error response from the server should include the string-to-sign server used right after the "Server used following string to sign" message. Could you please compare it with the one you logged?